# How contextmenu can made visible with right click outside the c# windows form application

Tags: c#

i have added contextmenu in richtextbox and it only appears inside richtextbox with right click. Now i want to make my context menu available outside the windows form application such as inside notepad,word etc.How can i made my context menu appear with right click anywhere? Your's suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
public Form1()
{            
        InitializeComponent();

        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("view meaning",new EventHandler(viewmeaning));
        menu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        richtextmeaning.ContextMenu = menu;

    }
    private void viewmeaning(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtword.Text = richtextmeaning.SelectedText;
        Btnsearch_Click(e,e);
    }
}
```

Then

Comment: Not possible. This sort of thing is a Shell extension. There is **a lot more involved** than what you've got here.

Comment: Example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus

Comment: @RBRKSharma A context menu is local to the control or application that creates it.You cannot use the contextmenu outside the application that created it.Whan you want is not exactly possible,you cannot change contextmenu of a compiled application such as **Notepad** or **Wordpad**.However you can create contextmenus for specific file types such as for **.txt** or **.rtf**.These type of contextmenus are called **Shell Extensions** which are registered COM Servers on the users computer.If you want to learn how to create shell extensions I would suggest you to visit link as referred by Simon.